# How to inflate string that we deflated with Java defaltor

Tags: java, php, android

I am deflating a string with java with this function:

```
protected static byte[] Compress(String source) {
    try {

        // deficne start time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //get bytes
        byte[] bytes = source.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(bytes);
        deflater.finish();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {

            int bytesCompressed = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesCompressed);
        }

        try {
            //close the output stream
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing the stream : " + ioe);
        }

        //get the compressed byte array from output stream
        byte[] compressedArray = bos.toByteArray();

        return compressedArray;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

now, I want to inflate that string with PHP with this function:

```
$uncompressed = gzinflate($filepath);
echo $uncompressed;
die();
```

but I got data error in php file, how can I solve this problem?

the error message is :

**Warning: gzinflate(): data error**

regards

Comment: You forgot to include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: thanks, I have added that

Comment: The first comment on this page looks like it might be relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php#112201